# Play Framework - how do I redirect to a page generated by a plugin controller? [SecureSocial]

Tags: http, scala, playframework-2.0, url-routing, securesocial

I have this in my routes.conf file:

```
# SecureSocial routes
# Login page
GET     /login                      securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login
```

And then I have this in a Scala Controller file

```
val index = SecuredAction { implicit request => 
    Redirect(routes.UserOps.watchlist)
    // how do I go straight to /login? >|
}
```

Doing this takes me to a login page that has a red error bar saying "you must be signed in to view this page". If I access `localhost:9000/login' I get the login page without the error bar.

Normally I do a `Redirect(routes.SomeControllerObject.ActionMethodName)` but in this case the controller I need to access is in a plugin...

I feel like I'm missing something rather large here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

To reverse-route to an action in a plugin controller you need to provide the correct, full path to the plugin's `routes` class.

```
Redirect(securesocial.controllers.routes.LoginPage.login)
```

***Original Answer***

For reverse-routing I don't think it matters where the `Controller` is since Play is building that when the project compiles. From the documentation:

> For each controller used in the routes file, the router will generate a ‘reverse controller’ in the `routes` package, having the same action methods, with the same signature, but returning a `play.api.mvc.Call` instead of a `play.api.mvc.Action`.

<strike>So this should work just as if `LoginPage` was a controller directly in your app.</strike>

```
Redirect(routes.LoginPage.login);
```

Comment: No... I get a compilation error: `value LoginPage is not a member of object controllers.routes`

Comment: I thought it put it all together but guess not. Try giving it the full path then.
`Redirect(securesocial.controllers.routes.LoginPage.login)`

Comment: Hm! No more compilation errors. I'm still getting the "you must be logged in to view that page" error bar though, so... ... the only way I've gotten my login page to show without the red prompt is to go to `localhost:9000/login` directly. I guess I'll need to do some sort of `GET /login` http request in my Action in order for this to happen

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you're asking then. Where are you trying to redirect from? If you are inside the `SecuredAction` code you originally posted and you're not logged in then I think it's always going to show the message... that's what the plugin does.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you want to redirect to the login page from SecuredAction? That's what SecuredAction does for you if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: It's more like I want to go directly to the login page from root / instead of being redirected. I want a "clean" login page so to speak.

Comment: So I think you just need to change your `/` route to point to a regular Action (not a SecuredAction) and have it redirect with `Redirect(securesocial.controllers.routes.LoginPage.login)`. Since it won't be going through the SecuredAction then it shouldn't show the "not logged in" message.

P.S. I updated my answer a bit since you accepted it and it had some incorrect info :P

Answer (score 1):

In order to show the message, you must have an item in the Flash. When you hit /login directly, there is no flash, so you won't see that message.

If you want to see that message:

`Redirect(securesocial.controllers.LoginPage.login).flashing( ... )`

Comment: I get a compilation error... `Overloaded method value [Redirect] cannot be applied to (play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])`